# Laravel reports error "Parameter must be an array or an object that implements Countable"

Tags: laravel-5.6

This is the error:

```
"count(): Parameter must be an array or an object that implements 
Countable (View: C:\xampp\htdocs\blog\resources\views\inc\sidebar.blade.php)"
```

This is my views/inc/sidebar.blade.php:

```
@if(count($articles)>0)
    @foreach($articles as $article)
        {{$article->title}}
    @endforeach
@endif
```

Here is my controller:

```
namespace App\Http\Controllers;
use Illuminate\Http\Request;
use App\Article;

class HomepageController extends Controller
{
   public function sidebar(){
        $articles = Article::orderBY('created_at', 'desc')->where('active', '1')->take(2)->get();
        return view('inc.sidebar')->with('articles', $articles);
    }
}
```

And on my views/pages/view_article.blade.php

```
@extends('layouts.layout')
@section('content')

<div class="container">
    <div class="row no-gutters" style="margin-top: 10px;margin-left: 5px;margin-right: 5px; min-height: 450px;">
        <div class="col-md-9 tex-justify">
            <table class="table-responsive">
                <tr><td>{{$articles->title}}</td></tr>
                <tr><td>{{$articles->created_at->format('M d Y')}}</td></tr>
            </table>
            <img src="/img/{{$articles->img_article}}">{!!$articles->body!!}</div>
        </div>
        <div class="col-md-3">
            @include('inc.sidebar')
        </div>
    </div>
</div><br>
@endsection
```

What am I doing wrong?

Answer (score 0):

The use of `orderBY` instead of `orderBy` might be the problem, but if that's not the issue, try replacing:

```
$articles = Article::orderBY('created_at', 'desc')->where('active', '1')->take(2)->get();
```

with:

```
$articles = Article::orderBy('created_at', 'desc')->where('active', '1')->take(2)->get()->all();
```

The reason behind this is that [`Illuminate\Database\Query\Builder::get`](https://laravel.com/api/5.6/Illuminate/Database/Query/Builder.html#method_get) returns an [`Illuminate\Support\Collection`](https://laravel.com/api/5.6/Illuminate/Support/Collection.html), not an array, whereas [`Illuminate\Support\Collection::all`](https://laravel.com/api/5.6/Illuminate/Support/Collection.html#method_all) returns a straight array containing the items in the collection which works with [`count`](http://php.net/manual/en/function.count.php).

Comment: yes @msbit orderBy might not be the issue because it is working on other pages. but sadly your suggestion did not solve the issue. Thanks anyway.

Comment: @juan-miguel does it give the exact same error or has that changed it somewhat?

Comment: it has the same error. The view_article.blade.php fetch data based on id. Thank you.

Comment: @juan-miguel if I understand correctly the original error was for `sidebar.blade.php`, so if the error now refers to `view_article.blade.php` that's something. In any case, it would be useful to see the controller code which renders that view.

Comment: I decided to give up the sidebar and move on. Thank you for your help anyway.

Answer (score 0):

Use `@if(isset($articles[0]->id)` instead of `@if(count($articles)>0)`